# UIAutomator running with espresso

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, android-espresso

I am currently testing an application that should be set as the default launcher.

I already have a set of `Espresso` tests running, but they only work if the user has previously selected my app as the launcher.

The dialog that appears to the user so that he can select the launcher is not reachable by `Espresso`, since it is outside the app itself. However, `UIAutomator` would be perfectly able to interact with it.

Hence, I would like to know if it is possible to use some kind of `UIAutomator` script before the `Espresso` tests.

Comment: If you solved your issue with the help of any answer below, please mark it as right one!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `UIAutomator 2.0` is now based on Android Instrumentation, you can run `Espresso` and `UIAutomator` tests in one test suite, for example. You can play with test methods naming to run UIAutomator tests first and then run other Espresso stuff. More about [UIAutomator 2.0](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator) and how to use it together with Espresso [here](https://testyour.app/blog/espresso-uiautomator).

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience yet with `uiatomator`, but I can provide you some useful links to start. Here they are:

#### To get more information about `uiautomator` visit these site:

- https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/uiautomator/index.html
- http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_ui_testing.htm

#### If you're looking for how to integrate `Espresso` with `uiatomator` visit:

https://testyour.app/blog/espresso-uiautomator

Hope it help