# Firebase Test Lab - How to perform Facebook Login in Robo Test?

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-android-sdk, firebase-test-lab

I'm testing my app with Robo test in Firebase Test Lab but my app can not start without Facebook Login and the Firebase emulator stuck at the Facebook Web Login.

I tried to record an "Espresso Test" and put my FB Test Login Credential but didn't work since it doesn't record the characters in the TextView in the Facebook Login WebView.

Is there any method by which I can put my Facebook test account credential to continue the test on the Firebase emulators?

Seems strange to me that Firebase built a good test environment but they can't put your FB credential for a test. (BTW I can't remove the Facebook Login because the app is based on FB information)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best path to take is learning how to use UI Automator to reach into a WebView to manipulate its elements, exposed by Android's accessibility APIs.  This is not straightforward, but definitely doable.

[Writing tests for an android app that logs into Facebook: UIAutomator can't fill in text in Facebook's username field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354049/writing-tests-for-an-android-app-that-logs-into-facebook-uiautomator-cant-fill)

Comment: You probably right but seem an hard path for me, Firebase should improve this is there is no other solution.

Answer (score 2):

As of 9th June 2020, Firebase Test lab robo script still doesn't support facebook login. It is stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-ux-test#scripting),

> Note: Robo script recordings don't capture your actions outside the
>   tested app. For example, logins through Facebook, Twitter, and other
>   social apps aren't recorded.

So you can't instruct the robo to input your facebook test credentials in the sdk login page through robo scripts.

### The hacky trick

However, I came up with a hacky trick to bypass facebook login. I introduce a hidden feature in alpha build (make sure it's not shipped to production), described below:

- When the version text in login screen is pressed 10 times I showed a dialog with EditText to input facebook access token manually.
- From the facebook developer console I created a [test user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users) and obtained it's access token
- I recorded the [robo script](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-ux-test#scripting) from the firebase assistant plugin in android studio.
- After inputting the access token in the dialog I executed the function that I call when I get access token from facebook sdk.
- I built a new app bundle and submitted it in the robo test along with the recorded robo script.

That's it. The facebook login is now bypassed. Here is the sample code,

```
    var fbTokenInputDialogVisibiltyCountDown = 0
    binding.textViewVersion.setOnClickListener {
        if (fbTokenInputDialogVisibiltyCountDown < 10) {
            fbTokenInputDialogVisibiltyCountDown = fbTokenInputDialogVisibiltyCountDown.inc()
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        val inputFbTokenBinding =
            ViewInputDialogBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()))
        AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setView(inputFbTokenBinding.root)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .setPositiveButton("Submit") { _, _ ->
                val fbAccessToken =
                    inputFbTokenBinding.editTextToken.value() // extension function show error for invalid input
                if (fbAccessToken.isNotEmpty()) onGetFacebookAccessToken(fbAccessToken)
            }
            .show()
        fbTokenInputDialogVisibiltyCountDown = 0
    }
```

I hope it helps. Let me know if you have any questions?