# Firebase - How to perform Robo Test with Facebook Login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-test-lab

I have an app that uses Firebase Facebook Authentication (and ONLY Facebook Authentication).  First screen users see has a button to perform login and nothing else relevant. The whole app depends on information coming from user's Facebook account (name, age, list of Friends). I tried to perform Firebase Robo Test, with a json script, but could not pass login screen.

In addition, it would also defeat the purpose of the test to upload an apk without login because I also call FB GraphRequest a few times after login to check some data validity, and I need the user to be logged in for that.

Any ideas on how to proceed in this case? Thanks.

Comment: I have some question, coz the documentation says Robo script cant record activity outside app like login with google, facebook etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Facebook Login in Firebase Test Lab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748370/how-do-facebook-login-in-firebase-test-lab)

Comment: To bypass fb login, you can follow the trick I showed in this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62273052/5465447