# Automated Facebook login using Espresso test suite on Android

Tags: android, facebook, unit-testing, testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to create an automated test suite for running in the Google Cloud Test Lab. My first activity is just a tutorial screen with a "Login with Facebook" button.

I'm trying to use Espresso to automatically input a test user email and password combination, but need the view ids. Any help?

Comment: You should use IUAutomator.I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805176/writing-tests-for-an-android-app-that-logs-into-facebook) can help.

Comment: @Alex I was able to do it using UI Automator after lots of tries. I'll try to post the answer here. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Check this out https://medium.com/azimolabs/android-webview-automation-testing-6311df8fe42e#.lvd7y9761